# Splash screen Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, splash-screen

I am beginner and I would like to show splash screen, but my boss wants to use Fragment. I do not know how to implement it in my MainActivity. I know that I have to use handler with time and stack layout, but I have not found how.
Thanks

Comment: you mean when the app is launching?

Comment: The first screen (layout) which is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need a handler to do this, follow these steps:

**1 -** Create an activity for the splash screen that launches your mainActivity after it's ready:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**2 -** The splash screen will have to be ready before the pap can even inflate a layout, so we create an xml file and define it as the window's background, here's an xml file with a grey background and an image in the center (called background_splash.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**3 -** Now go into your styles.xml and set a new style with this image we just created as it's background:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**4 -** Lastly you go into your manifest file, and define your SplashActivity as the launcher activity, and set your new style on it:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin #Kotlin #Splash #LuanchScreen

```
 private fun waitForWhile() {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        callNextActivity()
    }, 3000)

}

private fun callNextActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this,SignInActivity :: class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a Splash Screen as a Fragment inside your MainActivity

1. Add a FrameLayout to your MainActivity, inside the FrameLayout, make a Layout for your Views, and insert a Fragment which holds your SplashScreen            Display (Make sure your Fragment is in the bottom of the MainActivity, so that its displayed over your layout)

Example

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

         //Your UI goes here        

   </LinearLayout>


  <Fragment
      Your Fragment with Splash Screen Goes here 
   />
</FrameLayout>
```

2. In side your FragmentActivity do this

   ```
    new Handler()..postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() { 

          Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
          getActivity().finish();
          startActivity(intent);

     }
   },2000);
   ```

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what you mean by this: "Fragment which holds your SplashScreen Display (Make sure your Fragment is in the bottom of the MainActivity, so that its displayed over your layout)" 

Could you describe it in detail please?

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple in android we just use handler concept to implement the splash screen

**In your SplashScreenActivity java file paste this code.**

**In your SplashScreenActivity xml file put any picture using imageview.**

```
public void LoadScreen() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                 
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, AgilanbuGameOptionsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 2000); // you can increase or decrease the timelimit of your screen
    }
```